# I want to POST from React to an API created in Golang

Tags: reactjs, go, post

### What I want to do

I am creating a Todo app for my Golang studies.
I would like to read the data from POST requests in React with Golang.

### Code

go Backend

```
package todos

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
    "todo-app/auth"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

type Todo struct {
    // UserID    int       `json:"userid"`
    Todo      string    `json:"todo"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdat"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updatedat"`
}

type TodoBody struct {
    Todo string `json:"todo"`
}

func CreateTodo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")

    e := godotenv.Load()
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
    dbConnectionInfo := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/go_todo", os.Getenv("DB_USER"), os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"))
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbConnectionInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    tokenString := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
    tokenString = strings.TrimPrefix(tokenString, "Bearer ")

    log.Printf("request token=%s\n", tokenString)

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)

    }

    log.Printf("request body=%s\n", body)

    var data TodoBody

    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    // userId := 12
    todo := data.Todo

    todoData := Todo{todo, time.Now(), time.Now()}

    _, err2 := auth.TokenVerify(tokenString)
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {

        stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO todos (Todo,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt) VALUES(?,?,?)")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        _, err = stmt.Exec(todoData.Todo, todoData.CreatedAt, todoData.UpdatedAt)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(todoData)
    }
}
```

React Frontend

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useCreateTodo } from "../../hooks/useCreateTodo";
import { BaseButton } from "../atoms/baseButton";
import { TextArea } from "../atoms/textArea";

export const AddTodo = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const CreateTodo = useCreateTodo();
  const token = "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("token");

  const onClickCreate = () => {
    CreateTodo(token, text);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TextArea
        onChange={(e: any) => setText(e.target.value)}
        defaultValue=""
      />

      <BaseButton text="タスクを追加" onClick={onClickCreate} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

POST here ↓

```
import axios from "axios";

export const useCreateTodo = () => {
  const CreateTodo = (token: string, todo: any) => {
    const URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/createtodo";

    const data = { todo: todo };
    console.log(data);

    axios
      .post(URL, JSON.stringify(data), { headers: { Authorization: token } })
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return CreateTodo;
};
```

If I don't add a header when POST the correct value comes to Go's ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body), but if I add a header, I can't get the value.
When I hit Go's API with the Advanced REST client, it is processed correctly even with the header information, so I am wondering if there is a problem with the POST method, but I can't seem to solve the problem.
I would be grateful for your help. Best regards.

Comment: #1. What header are you having problems with? Is it the `{ Authorization: token }` in the react app? #2. How are you registering the `CreateTodo` handler in Go? With the stdlib `net/http`? Or are you using something else, like `gin`, `gorilla`, etc.? #3. Do you get some error output from the `log.Println`/`log.Fatal` statements in the Go code? If you do, what does the error say?

Comment: #1 Yes.　If I add { Authorization: token }, r.Body will be empty in go.
#2 I use net/http.
#3 If I add { Authorization: token },go output is 
2022/06/23 10:16:05 request token=
2022/06/23 10:16:05 request body=
2022/06/23 10:16:05 unexpected end of JSON input

If I delete  { Authorization: token },go output is 
2022/06/23 10:27:46 request body={"todo":"input todo"}

Comment: What does the browser's console say? When you open the network panel does the request sent with `axios` contain a body? Does it contain the auth header?

Comment: Browser console say
 POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/createtodo net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this code and it solved the problem..

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
    switch r.Method {
    case "OPTIONS":
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
        return
```

Thanks for your cooperation!